# How do i search the Folder which is in D drive using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I've a folder("App_data_payroll") which is in D Drive . I need to Find this folder and I need to copy the Files of that Folder, if the folder has files, and I have to paste that files in another folder using C#...

Comment: System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"D:\App_data_payroll")

Comment: @ AnjumSKhan Thanks for your Quick Reply, But I need to search that file with that name if exits then need to do some operations

Comment: @AnjumSKhan: the op is not aware of the path, then how it is possible to check with `System.IO.Directory.Exists()`

Comment: Hasnt anyone read what I read? "somewhere" means for me, that it could be be everywhere on D and that would mean, it would be a recursive task...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the folder path using GetDirectories, then loop over each file within the folder. Use System.IO.File.Copy to copy the files to a target location.

```
string dir = Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\","App_data_payroll").FirstOrDefault();
string targetPath = "D:\CopyToFolder\";

if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(dir))
{
    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir);

    // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist.
    foreach (string s in files)
    {
        var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
        var destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
        System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: ,ThankYou so much....

Comment: string targetPath = @"D:\CopyToFolder\";

Answer (score 0):

Try using Directory.GetDirectories() to get a list of directories matching your specific pattern.

```
Directory.GetDirectories(path, searchPattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function will help you to do this operation, this will accept two parameters

1. Directory name to search
2. Base directory ( in which search operation is performed), is optional

will collect the files within the directory and moved to specific location if exist

```
    private static void PerformFileCopy(string DirectoryToSearch, string BaseDirectory = @"D:\")
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(BaseDirectory))// check for existance of base directory to avoid throwing exception
        {
            var searchDir = Directory.GetDirectories(BaseDirectory).Where(x => new DirectoryInfo(x).Name == DirectoryToSearch).ToList();
            string copyToLocation = @"E:\newDir";
            if (searchDir.Count > 0) // True if such directory found
            {
                foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(searchDir[0])) // will iterate if Directory has files
                {
                    File.Copy(file, copyToLocation, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How to call this method:

option 1 : `PerformFileCopy("App_data_payroll");`

option 2 : `PerformFileCopy("App_data_payroll",@"D:\BaseFolder\MyDir");`

Comment: fine but let me know why

Comment: avoid modification once downvoted. your code is ridiculous.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan : thanks for the new information that **avoid modification once downvoted**

Comment: If everyone starts modifying their downvoted answers, then there would be no need for downvoting.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan: Kindly read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question            DO NOT comment without downvoting where a downvote would've been appropriate, hoping OP will fix their issues eventually, or that that one or two downvotes already on the question is enough ... poor them. You're killing the site if you do this. Questions with a few downvotes that get fixed can easily pick up enough upvotes again to reach a positive score.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that first check if folder exist on a specified path like this:

```
if(Directory.Exists("path"))
```

If the directory exists you can Copy its content to another folder using :

```
//copies all files in the folder
foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))
    File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(file)));
//copies all folders in the folder
foreach(var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir))
    Copy(directory, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(directory)));
```

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx